# Oracle 12cR1 - RMAN-11003, ORA-00354, ORA-00353 - Corrupt Redo Log

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, transaction-log, rman, corruption

Oracle 12cR1, disaster database.

> ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
>
> ORA-00354: corrupt redo log block header
>
> ORA-00353: log corruption near block 8 change 80357235718 time
> 11/01/2020 01:57:01
>
> ORA-00334: archived log: '/FRA/.../o1_mf_2_61264_hsvvjoyb_.arc'

Database in mount mode and can't recover.

How can I resolve this?

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not an online redo log. That is an archived redo log of thread 2 sequence 61264. It can be clearly seen from the error and the name of the file. The archivelog on disk was damaged. Restore it from backup and continue recovery using that.

If you do not have a backup of that archivelog, just roll forward the standby database with an incremental backup.

As a last resort, you can rebuild the standby database from the primary.

Comment: Could the same archived redo log be damaged on the production server? In this case, the full database backup may not be available.

Comment: @jrdba You will know that once you check it. Even if the same archivelog was damaged on the primary system, you can always use a new full backup or active duplicate to rebuild the standby from scratch. With incremental backup that archivelog is also not needed in this scenario.

Comment: Okay. I'm researching how can I find it on production database. Thank you.

Comment: Hi sir, it solved. I backuped database from production according time of archivelog and recover it from disaster side. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a Service Request with Oracle Support for specific instruction. For an overview of the situation, see here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00354_corrupt_redo_log_block_header.htm

Comment: It's not a problem for us, because it's a disaster server. But 'alter database clear unarchived logfile 'logilename';' can it resolve the problem?